# Efficient algorithm for computing fastest time on distance interval

Tags: algorithm

I would like to know if there are any efficient algorithm recommendations, that are fast and do not consume too many resources, for computing the fastest interval of distance in a sequence of data. In other words an algorithm that returns the minimum amount of time on an interval of n meters, from a data set.

Eg:

**Input**

- data_list: [{distance: 0, time:0},{distance: 1m, time:2s},{distance: 4m, time:4s}...{distance:10000m, time: 3600s}]
- distance_interval: 345m

**Output**

- fastest_interval_start_distance: 7655 m
- fastest_interval_end_distance: 8000 m
- fastest_interval_time: n seconds

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the following solution that has a complexity running time of O(n). With the help of memoization to avoid recomputing data that has already been traversed.

It works by having a min index and max index that are associated with the minimum time.

1. min index starts at index 0, time 0, and fastest_interval_start_distance 0
2. max index is assigned as soon as distance_interval is achieved and fastest_interval_end_distance contains the distance value at such index
3. the sum of the time difference between data items is stored in fastest_interval_time
4. min index and max index start to move forward as distance increases with each data item.
5. If the sum of time differences between min and max is less than fastest_interval_time, the current output is updated including fastest_interval_start_distance and fastest_interval_end_distance and fastest_interval_time
6. Edge cases include when the data set is empty or distance_interval is greater than the total distance.
   Thank you!